# What is the default theme name in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, themes

On a submitted bug report I was asked whether I am using the default theme of Ubuntu 16.04. However, I could not find any information about the name of the default theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default theme is called Ambiance.

To find this out, press <kbd>Super</kbd> to open the Dash and search for "Appearance". Click on the "Theme" dropdown box and you will see an entry called "Ambiance *(default)*".

If you're filing bug reports, you might need to know the package name containing the theme. The package name of Ambiance (and its light counterpart Radiance) theme is `light-themes`.